# How to accept multiple clients at the same time using a TCP connection?

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

I have a Server that create a TCP connection via Socket with a Client. Since my app should be a Chat I need the server to accept multiple clients simultaneously using the same port, so that they can comunicate in real-time. 
My Server-side is a Java application, my Client-side is an Android app.

Is possible to do something like this? If yes how can I do it?

This is my server code:

```
public class Server {

public static void main(String[] args){

    ServerClass server = new ServerClass();
    server.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    server.inizia();
     }
}




public class ServerClass extends JFrame {

JTextArea testoarea;
String messaggio;
ObjectOutputStream output;
DataInputStream input;
ServerSocket server;
Socket connessione;

public ServerClass(){
    super("Server in Ascolto");
    testoarea = new JTextArea();
    add(new JScrollPane(testoarea));
    setSize(600, 700);
    setVisible(true);


}
public void inizia()
{
    try {

        server = new ServerSocket(7100);
        while(true)
        {
            try {

                iniziaConnessione();
                sistemaCanali();
                chatta();
                //closeCrap();

            } catch (EOFException eofException) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                showMessage("Il Server ha perso la connessione..\n");
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException ioException) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        ioException.printStackTrace();
    }


}

private void iniziaConnessione() throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    showMessage("Aspetto qualcuno per connettermi.... \n");
    connessione = server.accept();
    showMessage("Mi sono connesso a qalcuno... \n");

}

private void sistemaCanali() throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    output = new ObjectOutputStream(connessione.getOutputStream());
    output.flush();
    input = new DataInputStream(connessione.getInputStream());
    showMessage("I canali sono apposto...  \n");
}


private void chatta() throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String messaggio = "Sei connesso e pronto a chattare... \n";
    showMessage(messaggio);
    messaggio = (String) input.readUTF();
    showMessage("Client - " + messaggio);
    sendData(messaggio);


}
private void sendData(String messaggio2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
        output.writeUTF(messaggio2);
        output.flush();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        showMessage("ERRORE: non riesco a inviare il messaggio...  \n");
    }
}
private void showMessage(final String text) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
                new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        testoarea.append(text);
                    }
                }
            );
} 


}
```

Comment: "Is it possible.." questions are often rhetorical. If you've ever used software that does as much (and you have!) then it's definitely possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have accepted a client, use another thread to manage the comunications with it.  Don't manage your communications in the same thread that that running your `accept()` loop.  Your client thread(s) can then pass data back and forth between the clients as needed, without interfering with the server's ability to accept new clients at the same time.